# VB.NET select link from listbox and browse to it in webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, listbox

I have a list of links stored in a listbox. I want a timer control to load one link after the other every 4 seconds, and once it's reached the end of the list, I want the timer to stop. I've tried to achieve this with the code below and it's only loading the first link. Can someone point out my mistake(s)? Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim counter As Integer = counter + 1
    If counter > ListBox2.Items.Count Then
        counter = 0
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    Else
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(ListBox2.Items(i))
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your `counter` variable at the class level instead of within your Tick handler, or else its value is always reinitialized to 1.

So in other word, defined it oustide the handler.

Also, you must not loop the entire content of the ListBox within your tick handler.

Here's a better version:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private counter As Integer = 0

    ...

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        If counter > ListBox2.Items.Count - 1  Then
            counter = 0
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        Else
             WebBrowser1.Navigate(ListBox2.Items(counter))
        End If
        'Increment at the end to get element(0)
        counter = counter + 1

    End Sub
End Class
```

Cheers

Comment: That's true, but it's not the only problem here. The entire loop is within the tick event.

Comment: @mrlucmorin The correct is `If counter > ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 Then`

Comment: @valter, you can propose an edit if you want. I'll modify it, but you can always edit it yourself ;-)

Comment: I know that, but i know also how "sensitive" high rated users are, so i prefered to comment. This doesn't apply to you of course.

Comment: Hehe, got ya... In this case I had simply copied/pasted the original code, moved the increment to the end, but forgot to update the condition.. thx for spotting it.